# Proving alternative of Integration by Parts from Stegun's Book and its Definite form

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I only knew 1 kind of integration by parts given by this:
$$\int u\, \Bbb dv = uv - \int v \,\Bbb du\tag{1}$$
And i can understand where it came from.

And the definite integral form is:
$$\int_a^b u\, \Bbb dv = uv\,\Bigg|_a^b - \int_a^b v \,\Bbb du\tag{2}$$

From Stegun's Book, i found another interesting form of integration by parts given by:
$$\int uv \Bbb dx = \left(\int u\Bbb dx\right)v - \int\left(\int u \Bbb dx\right)\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx} \Bbb dx\tag{3}$$.

Maybe i can derive it using the product rule of differentation:

$$\begin{align}
D_x\left[(u(x)v(x))\right] &= u'(x)v(x) + u(x)v'(x) \\
\int D_x\left[(u(x)v(x))\right] \Bbb dx&= 
\int u'(x)v(x) + u(x)v'(x)\Bbb dx\\
uv &= \int v \Bbb du + \int u \Bbb dv
\end{align}$$

But what now?

My question is, what's the "definite" integral form of Eq. $(3)$? And how to prove it? (I confuse with $\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx}$) and which parts are evaluated from $a$ to $b$ for the definite integral form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same rule, it just uses different terms.  In the second formula, $u$ is now $v$, and $v$ has become $\int u\,dx$, or put otherwise, $dv$ has become $u\,dx$.

Comment: What about the definite integral form? Is it like $$\int_a^b uv \Bbb dx = \left(\int_a^b u\Bbb dx\right)v - \int_a^b\left(\int_a^b u \Bbb dx\right)\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx} \Bbb dx$$. ?

Comment: Are $v$ and $v'$ evaluated from $a$ to $b$ or not?